# Android: Dialog crashes in Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I have a class with a thread and a progress dialog. When the thread stops, the dialog must dismiss. But if the thread stops, the app crashes :S Has anyone an idea whats wrong?

```
public class Main extends Activity {
```

public static ProgressDialog LoadingDialog = null;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  LoadingDialog.show(AndroidRSSReader.this, "Laden...", "Even geduld aub...", true);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  startUp();

new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {

```
         try {
 Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
}
         LoadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
```

}

Comment: what's the exception you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have problems in dismissing a dialog try using a Handler to perform an action on UI thread :

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // perform logic
    if(LoadingDialog!=null)//first check if dialog is not null.This might be a reason for crashing
     LoadingDialog.dismiss();
    LoadingDialog=null
    }

    };
```

& then call it in your activity by simply calling `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`
&you are done.

Additional advice :also have a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform async operation.

Answer (score 3):

`LoadingDialog` is still null when you call dismiss.  You need to make sure and assign it to something (like your progress bar).

```
LoadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidRSSReader.this, "Laden...", "Even geduld aub...", true);
```